# trying to extend golang pigpio wrapper functions gpioWaveAddGeneric

Tags: c, go, raspberry-pi

Good Day,

I tried to extend this [library](https://github.com/go-pigpio/pigpio) on GitHub but it does not work and I got this error. `pigpio.go:319:48: undefined: Pulse`

This is the function:

```golang
func gpioWaveAddGeneric(numPulses uint, pulse *Pulse) (err error) {
 totalPulses := int(C.gpioWaveAddGeneric(
   C.unsigned(numPulses), &pulse[0]))
 if totalPulses > 0 {
   // totalPulses = the new total number of pulses in the current waveform   
   // if OK, otherwise PI_TOO_MANY_PULSES$
  } else {
    // handle erroer err = Errno(totalPulses)
  }
  return
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you so much!

Comment: [An issue](https://github.com/go-pigpio/pigpio/issues/1) in the `pigpio` project mirroring this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what do you mean by using the verb "extend",
but if you merely trying to *use* that library in your own code,
the appearance of an unqualified type name `Pulse` in your code looks quite suspiciously:
to use a package, you first `import` it and then refer to the symbols it *exports* using the form `packagename.Symbol`.

That is, in this very case you should have done something like

```golang
import "github.com/go-pigpio/pigpio"

func gpioWaveAddGeneric(numPulses uint, pulse *pigpio.Pulse) (err error) {
```

If you *really* are trying to extend that libary — by writing custom code *in* it — then it's perfectly sensible to use unqualified names but
then a possible hunch to why it does not work may be the appearance of a so-called "build constraint"

```golang
// +build ignore
```

in the file containing the definition of the Go type `Pulse` (search the repository for the "type Pulse" substring).

[The documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) explicitly states that the file containing such a constraint is excluded from the build (that is, is not compiled at all), and that means neither the code of that package itself, nor its clients do not see the symbol `Pulse` at all.

Why is that, is out of the scope of the present discussion; I'd ask the package's author. (Well, [blaming that file](https://github.com/go-pigpio/pigpio/blame/master/pigpio/pigpio-godefs.go) tells that it was actually born right with that constraint; it may suggest the author did not think the file is complete and/or fit for being used.)